# How to create a new empty jagged array with same dimensions as another without loops

Tags: c#, arrays, dimension

Is it possible to do this without having to use a loop in my source code?

```
T[][] output = new T[array.Length][];
for (int i=0; i<array.Length; i++)
{
    T[i] = new T[array[0].Length];
}
```

Or should I write a function to do it?

Assume the array is rectangular in dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
T[][] output = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Length)
               .Select(x => new T[array[0].Length])
               .ToArray();
```

But this way is also using loops behind the scenes..